# How do I import contacts onto a Shared Publication List?

Tags: data-import

I'm trying to add contacts to a shared publication list. The list is created with the correct fields, but when we go into the list there is only the option to export.

Wondering how to get the contacts on my csv onto it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use data loader to import or export data to the required object in salesforce